# Laravel - How to release only API routes

Tags: php, laravel, url, laravel-10

I developed a web application with React frontend and Laravel for stateless API.

I would like to access to the frontend with the url "http://localhost/my-application" and the backend's API with the url "http://localhost/api/my-application/".

I created the folder "www/api/my-application" and here I put a symlink of public index.php of my Laravel backend.

The problem is that to call the APIs, I have to put this url "http://localhost/api/my-application/api/login".

As you can see I have to repeat "/api" because Laravel APIs have that default url. Also, if I try to just access to just "http://localhost/api/my-application/" I get a page with 500 Server Error, and the log says

> ERROR: View [welcome] not found. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): View [welcome] not found.

This is because it tries to access to the view. But I don't have any views, I would like that my Laravel project has just API stuff

How to clean the project so that I just have to access to "http://localhost/api/my-application/" to access to the APIs? So the "login" API, should be here: "http://localhost/api/my-application/login" and not here "http://localhost/api/my-application/api/login"

Comment: If you are using an older laravel boilerplate (v10 and before) you should have [this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php#L33) file and you can remove the `prefix('api')` line from that (you don't intend to use web routes so it shouldn't really be a problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the prefix for routes in `RouteServiceProvider.php`

From this

```
$this->routes(function () {
     Route::middleware('api')
        ->prefix('api')
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

     Route::middleware('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
});
```

To this

```
$this->routes(function () {
     Route::middleware('api')        
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

     Route::middleware('web')
        ->prefix('web')
        ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
});
```

In this way you are removing the prefix for API routes and adding a prefix `web/` to web routes.

Then from your frontend just hit the endpoint
`http://localhost/api/my-application/login`

Also, you could give a try by removing the `web` Route middleware from provider to disable it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I removed `->prefix('api')` and I removed the middleware web call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way as mentioned in the comment:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => '/api/v1'], static function (Router $router): void {
    ...
    $router->get('login', [AccessController::class, 'show']);
    ...
});
```